# how to figure out the amount of memory a 2D vector is taking currently in C++

Tags: c++, string, memory, vector

I have a 2D vector `vector<vector<int>> data`. I want to know the total memory it is taking after a while. I can iterate through the vector and add the size of each inner vector but is there a better way of doing so?

Follow up: if I have a `vector<string> data`. Is there a way to get the memory it is taking after a while without iterating through the vector?

Comment: Rough idea: Add up all the `length` values and multiply by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Have you used any *memory profiling* tools?

Comment: Do you really want to know the amount of *memory* used, or jsut the total number of elements? If actual memory, why do you need to know that? What is the problem that's supposed to solve?

Comment: By the way, even if you count the size of all elements and all objects, it still won't be the true size used, since the allocator itself could have added some internal meta-information for each allocation. There might also be padding for alignment reasons. And the operating system itself is typically allocating *pages* to a process not individual bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `vector` class, you'll have to iterate. Or maybe there is some function that will do this with some magic syntax, but there will still be an iteration going on under the hood.

So if you want to avoid the iteration, then you probably have to write a new container class that supports what you want. Or at least some wrapper class.

In practice, I see two possible ways of calculating the size:

1. Iterate every element like you're doing now
2. Recalculate the size every time you add or remove an element

Here is an (incomplete) example that shows the idea:

```
class MyContainer   {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
    int total_size;

public:
    void push_back(int pos, int val) {
        data[pos].push_back(val);
        total_size++;
    }

    int size() {
        return total_size;
    }
};
```

Remember though that this will keep track of the number of elements. If you multiply them by `sizeof (int)` you'll get an approximation of the memory usage. But it will not include the overhead for storing things. And a bigger factor is that classes like `vector` typically reserves more memory than needed in order to avoid having to allocate each time you add a new element.

So if you want to use the `vector` class, you would get a better approximation of memory usage by iterating over `capacity` instead of `size`. But then you're back to iterating. Because you cannot hook the allocation as easy as you can with `push_back`. But it's possible. Here is a rough idea for that:

```
class MyContainer   {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
    std::vector<int> capacity;
    int total_capacity;

public:
    void push_back(int pos, int val) {
        data[pos].push_back(val);
        total_capacity += data[pos].capacity - capacity[pos];
        capacity[pos] = data[pos].capacity;
    }

    int capacity() {
        return total_capacity;
    }
};
```

This does not take the extra size of `MyContainer::capacity` but you could modify the code to account for that.

Comment: Just adding the element sizes won't calculate the real memory consumption of the container. You'll have to take in  account the management variables of the vector itself, and the reserved memory capacity, and the overhead allocations have due to alignment and other restructoins you have to know for the actual OS and MM system.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm writing about that atm